# Is a large-scale simulation of movable land possible?

Tags: simulations

I was recently reading about a nuclear waste containment area buried far beneath the desert in New Mexico (WIPP), and upon looking at diagrams I wondered if it would be possible to create something of the sort in a game/sandbox.

Imagine a square mile of land with packed yet completely movable sand/soil that can be excavated using any tools you see necessary. Under the soil would be rock that can be drilled or broken through just as in real life. Think Minecraft, but without the blocks and instead particles that behave near how they would in the real world.

What's stopping games/sims like this from being created, and is there any prospect of a realistic earth-moving sandbox in the future?

Comment: What specific obstacle would make this impossible? What challenge or snag have you encountered in trying to implement it?

Comment: @DMGregory, i'm assuming that a simulation on such a scale would require an extremely large amount of processing power, even if only the section of particles around the player were being actively simulated. I am fairly new in game development, and my question is more geared towards the absence of this type of game seeing as I don't have the ability to create it currently. It is a good goal to set myself though!

Comment: This site is for getting help developing games and mods. If you're not trying to develop this game, then the question is not on-topic here. If you are trying to develop this game, then the way to determine whether modern computers are able to handle the type of simulation you have in mind is to prototype a rough sample and profile its performance. If you run into trouble, you can ask here about approximation & optimization strategies.

Comment: Keep in mind that simulations for video games need to be fun, not accurate. You can cut a lot of corners when the result is just supposed to look correct and nobody cares if it actually is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible? Heck, I created one!

This video shows an excavator digging and ripping soil.
It also has a bulldozer "moving" a hill-side.

Also, it is a real 3D terrain, not just a height map.
Which means you can dig overhangs, or tunnels if need be.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54o1fttLqQs

Done with a dual-representation of particles, that are fused into soil by running Marching Cubes over a 3D scalar field.

Note that it is free on steam if you want to try it out for yourself.

[image]